# Algorithms: Recurrence

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

Here's a problem that I am struggling with...
If two algorithms A and B both solve the same problem. On an input of size $n$

1. Algorithm $A$ breaks it into $5$ pieces of size $n/2$, recursively solves each piece, and then combines the solutions in time n.
2. Algorithm $B$ breaks it into $4$ pieces of size $n/2$, recursively solves each piece, and then combines the solutions in time $n^{1.5}$.
   Which algorithm has better asymptotic running time?

**(1)** would be $T(n) = 5 \cdot T(n/2) + n$

**(2)** would be $T(n) = 4 \cdot T(n/2) + n^{1.5}$ ?

How would I approach this?

Comment: Do you have the "Master Theorem" available?

Comment: Yes. I do have it.

Comment: x @user: Apply it to each of your two recurrences; it will produce tight asymptotic bounds for their solutions. Compare these bounds.